# python - handle connection exception (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that is running fine until it throws a connection exception and stops the whole program. How can I deal with (ignore) this exception? As you can probably tell I have never dealt with this kind of thing in Python before

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to implement a try/except block. [RealPython has a good tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/) on handling exceptions gracefully but the basic structure is as follows:

```
try:
   # some code that may produce an exception
except: # this will catch any exceptions, which is generally bad practice
   # code to execute ONLY if there is an exception
else:
   # code to execute ONLY if there is NOT an exception
finally:
   # code to run regardless, often used for clean up
```

Only the `try` and `except` blocks are necessary; the `else` and `finally` blocks are optional. As I mentioned above, it is typically bad practice to catch all errors by just using the except keyword. Instead, you want to catch specific errors like in the following example:

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
try:
   # some code that may produce an exception
except ConnectionError: # this will only catch ConnectionErrors
   # code to execute ONLY if there is a ConnectionError
else:
   # code to execute ONLY if there is NOT a ConnectionError
finally:
   # code to run regardless, often used for clean up
```

Comment: that makes sense to me, but i'm struggling to understand the import process of an exception, `from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError` didnt work for me

Comment: Importing an exception/error is conceptually similar to importing an object. I'm not quite sure why you'd be having trouble importing `ConnectionError`. Is it `ImportError: No module named requests`? If so, you many need to install `requests` with `pip`. Otherwise, post the message and I'll be more than happy to take a look in a little bit.

Comment: i got it, just forgot to double check (i wrote `request.` instead of `requests.`.)
however, it struggles to continue the script as a variable that was defined inside the "try" was referenced soon afterwards

Comment: Is the try block within a loop or something where you could use `continue` inside the `except` block if you see a ConnectionError? If it is within a function, could you `pass` inside the `except` block?